# Xamarin Forms shows for IValueConverter error when compile

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, ivalueconverter

I want to create in xamarin forms value converter for Rg Plugins Popup it should show Yes or No (True/False) but when I compile it shows:

Position 14:14. Type cnv:BoolToStringConverter not found in xmlns clr-namespace:RodoAcceptance.Converters;assembly=RodoAcceptance   RodoAcceptance

This is XAML View and value converter

[image]

Code behind:

[image]

[image]

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters#binding-converter-propertiesyou have not supplied a TypeArgument for <T>

Answer (score 0):

If your converter has a `TypeArgument` `<T>`, you should use it in following way:

```
<Label>
    <Label.Text>
        <Binding Source="{x:Reference switch1}"
                     Path="IsToggled">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <local:BoolToObjectConverter x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                                                 TrueObject="Of course!"
                                                 FalseObject="No way!" />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </Label.Text>
</Label>
```